# DNN User Accounts Module Error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I moved my working DNN solution to a different server but after that the user accounts module does not work. When I click 'Users' on the control panel and enter the username and search I am able to pick up the user I searched for but when I click on 'Manage Roles' it gives me the following error:

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am on version 4.7.0. I am using active directory.

Please help.

Comment: What is the URL of the page that isn't found? You really should upgrade DNN as well, 4.7 has some massive security issues

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using SSL? You might look at the TABS table to see if any of the Admin pages are marked as SECURE